# Changing .net asp mvc 4 culture info, application wide

Tags: asp.net-mvc, globalization, cultureinfo

I have a complete application, which uses a web app, a database, and some business logic layer. The problem is that each one of them is configured to use the system culture. I need to fix the culture to invariant or the standard one in all of them. I have tried adding to the globalization tag in web.config but I'm still having issues, it doesnt seem to work.

I also added the "globalize.js" script to  my layout page so scripts would work just as the rest of the system but it doesn't work either.

Comment: plz share more detail what you exactly want to achieve and what approach you implemented...

Answer (score 5):

try to add this code to the global.asax

```
using System.Globalization;
    using System.Threading;
    protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string lang = Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["culture"].ToString();
        //CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;//if need invariant
        CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(lang);

        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
    }
```

works for me

Comment: This would only affect the web app culture wouldnt it? I also need it to affect the business logic and database, otherwise there would be missmatches

Comment: Unless you are creating new threads, this should do it.  This will set the culture info on the thread at the beginning of the request, which (in most cases) will be the same thread on which business and data logic execute.